# Increase Ms Access Insert Performance

Tags: sql, ms-access, insert, ms-access-2010, query-performance

I am using MS Access 2010, split in front end / back end; on a network drive (WAN) with 16+ table with one table of **users (1.3 Million)** which is mostly used for user information and is not insert heavy and few other tables, which will receive **upto 2000+ inserts daily**.

I have been able to optimize most of the read/select queries. Although 1 chunk of my code looks as below. This can be used for upto 2000 iterations daily.

```
Do Until rec.EOF
    Dim vSomeId As Integer
    vSomeId = rec!SomeId

    'StrSQL = StrSQL & "INSERT INTO TransportationDetails ( TransportationId, SomeId)" & _
        '"VALUES(" & vTransportationId & ", " & vSomeId & ");"

    StrSQL = "INSERT INTO TransportationDetails ( TransportationId, SomeId)" & _
        "VALUES(" & vTransportationId & ", " & vSomeId & ");"

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL (StrSQL)
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True


    rec.Edit
    rec!SomeBoolean = rec!SomeOtherBoolean 
    rec.Update
    rec.MoveNext
Loop
```

My objective here, is to **reduce the number of calls to the db** to insert all the values. and **MS ACCESS does NOT support having more than 1 query in a statement**, as I tried in the commented part of the code. I also think the recordset upate method is a lot time consuming, and if any one can suggest a better way to update the recordset.

**Is** there any way I can trick Access to insert & Update in **less hits to db** through SQL Queries, or any other access feature. Or optimize in anyway, It can take up to 30 mins some time. Decreasing it to  At least 2 - 5 mins will be appropriate.

P.S.
I can not switch to SQL Server, It is **JUST NOT POSSIBLE**. I am aware it can be done in way more optimal way through sql server and Access shouldn't be used for WAN, but I don't have that option.

Solution:
I went with Andre's and Jorge's solution. The time decreased by 17 times. Although Albert's Answer is correct too as I found my main issue was with the sql statements in a loop. Changing the edits in the recordset to sql didnt impact much on the time factor.

Comment: You should use an Insert Select query. Do it with your `REC` query in conjuntion with your insert query like `INSERT INTO TransportationDetails ( TransportationId, SomeId) select " & vTransportationId & ", someId from rectable where ....` You would call this insert just once

Comment: I have a access query that is a recordset for the "rec" recordset. Can I run the select statement of this query, or I will have to rewrite the query in this sql statement?

Comment: If you use it in another places you would have to create a new one for the inserts, but if it exists just to this insert you just need one as the answer given below based on my sugestion.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt comments. The performance increased by 17 times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have now

```
S = "SELECT SomeId, SomeBoolean, SomeOtherBoolean " & _
    "FROM recTable WHERE someCriteria"
Set rec = DB.OpenRecordset(S)
```

change your statements into

```
"INSERT INTO TransportationDetails (TransportationId, SomeId) " & _
"SELECT " & vTransportationId & ", SomeId " & _
"FROM recTable WHERE someCriteria"
```

and

```
"UPDATE recTable SET SomeBoolean = SomeOtherBoolean WHERE someCriteria"
```

For performance, avoid looping over Recordsets where possible. Use SQL statements that operate on whole sets instead.

Answer (score 8):

I should point out that in the case of inserting rows, you will find FAR better performance by using a recordset. A SQL “action” query will ONLY perform better if you operating on a set of data. The instant you are inserting rows, then you don’t have a “set” insert, and using a DAO recordset will result in MUCH better performance (a factor of 10 to 100 times better).

Comment: Good advice (as usual). I just did a quick test and 2000 SQL INSERTs took 24 seconds while 2000 DAO.Recordset AddNew inserts into the same table took less than 0.2 seconds.

Comment: I tested insert using the marked answer on 1447 inserts and it took me less than 2 seconds. My previous way of looping through and having 1 sql insert statement for each was taking 35 seconds.

Comment: Although I was editing those 1447 records through the recordset and I didnt found any significant improvement after changing it from the recordset to a single sql statement.

Comment: Above comments and results quite much matches the general experience of the Access community. As noted, if you can do a update using a single SQL statement, then you see good performance, but in general not a lot more then a loop+edit. If you turn off row locking, then you will again gain some additional performance gains, but also reduce bloat of the file by large amounts when doing many edits.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal How do you turn off row locking? Is it off by default when using a recordset?

Comment: The row  locking setting is active or not regardless if you set or use any locking in a form or code. the option is specifly called [x] use row locking. This works by expanding all records to the size of one data page, so the result is a fake row lock because access has page locking, but not true row locking. It is this huge expanding issue that causes this issue. File->options->client settings->scroll down to [x] Open databases by using record-locking. You have to exit + re-start (so, un-check this option - it is rare required).

Comment: I'd like to add it depends on the structure of the code. I used DAO.Recordset but I open the table with 6 million+ records, write a record and then close it, but this process happens thousands of times and bogs down the process.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into a problem where I have to import 200,000 records into 12 Access tables every 6 hours. This took too long as I was inserting each record one at a time.

I picked up a tip from a colleague who suggested using Linked Tables.

So I set up a linked table in my Access Database which was linked to a semi-colon delimited text file.

My program then created that semi-colon delimited text file every 6 hours.

You then select from the linked table into the table needed and that table is created.

This made my process immensely faster and I would definitely suggest it as an option.